# Strange issue with In App-purchase system IOS, sandbox and live App Store environments

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, receipt

I have recently developed a In App-purchase system to my IOS app. I have tested it in the apple sandbox-environment and everything works great. So far I have made a simple solution with saving the receipt locally in the app after it being purchased.

But once live at the App Store a strange bug occurred. If a user purchased the app and then shuts it down (the app) and then restarts it again the receipt gets lost, for some reason?. Since I am not able to recreate the bug in the sandbox-environment I can not debug the code and I do not know where to start.

I find the scenario very odd and confusing, if someone ever experienced something similar or have built many In-App  purchase systems within IOS, please share your knowledge or ideas.

Comment: How are you saving the receipt locally? Show your code.

Comment: My hunch is that you are saving it in a place that won't persist beyond the session. Perhaps you need to save it to the Docs Directory or NSUserDeafaults, etc...

Comment: Please check this LINK : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide.pdf

Comment: While uploading your app on itunes you have to check InApp Purchase...